# WPF Playing Windows Media Codec 9?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Dear Guys
I have a simple wpf app with some local videos , my videos are currently encoded with wm9
But unfortunately wpf Media Element is unable to control over windows media player 9, the minimum requirement is wmp 10 , i don't want to upgrade user windows media player specially in xp , can you provide me a solution to this situation !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMP 10 is supported in XP, at least with SP3. If you're not on SP3, there are far greater issues than just the media player version.

But to answer your question, I'm pretty sure Microsoft has deprecated WMP 9. What you could do is hand off control through a Process.Start() command, referencing your video in the arguments. That will launch the player outside your UI and hand control to WMP 9.

Alternatively, you might have to consider retail-cost 3rd party controls.

Comment: thanks but could you also suggest any 3rd-party control to fit this situation

Comment: Sorry; I tend to roll my own controls. Some bigger names in WPF controls are Infragistics and DevExpress. You might try to find a WinForms control which supports WMP9 and host it in the WPF WinForms container, but you'll have to worry about airspace issues if you did that.